# Replace specific words using regular expression (globally) - Java

Tags: java, regex, textpad

I am trying to come up with a regular expression to replace specific words irrespective of position / order but it doesn't seem to work

Example input:

```
This is a a an the a the testing
```

regex:

```
(\sa\s)|(\san\s)|(\sthe\s)
```

Actual output:

```
This is a the the testing
```

Expected output:

```
This is testing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex fails to match some `a` or `an` or `the` substrings, it's mainly because of the overlapping matches.That is, in this string `foo an an an`, the above regex would match the first `<space>an<space>`, and it won't match the second `an` because the first match also consumes the space which exits before the second `an` .

```
string.replacaAll("\\s(?:an|the|a)(?=\\s)", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yV8tG2/2)

The above regex would fail if any one of the strings would present at the last. In that case, you could use this,

```
String test = "a an the an test is a success and an example";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\s(?:an|the|a)(?=\\s|$)|^(?:an|the|a)(?=\\s)", "").trim());
```

**Output:**

```
test is success and example
```

Comment: Looks like its not replacing the first word.. 'the test is a success and an example' returns 'the test is success and example'

Comment: check the regex in the comment.

Comment: Tried 'a an the an test is a success and an example' it still returns 'an test is success and example'.. trying to get rid of 'an' at the start